# Performance issue with redux / redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

We've been using redux-form and seeing a noticeable lag when user types in an input field. I'm not really sure if it's a problem with redux-form. This could probably be the way we've structured our components. So we have page which lists some data, say 25 rows and filters for it. On click of a button, we open a modal where we render a redux-form. Now if user types in any of the input field, all the list items in the underlying page also get re-rendered. We're using React.Component for list items. React devtool's "Highlight updates" option highlights list items but when I do a console.log in list item's render method, it's not printing!

Wonder if this is happening because the list item's parent component is also a (redux) connected component and when redux-form's Field updates the store, this also gets re-rendered? How do you use redux-form in such scenario? I don't think having multiple stores is a recommended way.

Comment: Why don't you create a modal in new component? You don't have to put modal and list in same component. Making new component for modal will resolve the problem in my opinion.

Comment: Modal is actually a separate component having only the form.

Comment: Did you connect form component with redux form? The list container should not be updated, because none of states or props are updated. I think you missed something

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have an event listener for when any of the inputs on the form changes, and then you do some fetching/filtering on the underlying list?

Running this when typing quickly could lead to a performance hit, depending on what your event listener does. You could try using something like [lodash.debounce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.debounce) to only run your listener after the user has stopped typing for like 200ms?